# Getting all unique/distinct elements from a many to many field django

Tags: mysql, django

Say that I have this structure:

```
class Distinct_Alert(models.Model):
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(to='Entity', through='Entity_To_Alert_Map')
    objects = Distinct_Alert_Manager()
    has_unattended = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    latest_alert_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Entity_To_Alert_Map(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    distinct_alert = models.ForeignKey(Distinct_Alert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity_alert_relationship_label = models.TextField()


class Entity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=700, blank=False)
    related_entities = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    identical_entities = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    objects = Entity_Manager()
```

disregarding the other fields, what I'm trying to do is get all the unique entities from a selection of distinct alerts. So say that I pull 3 distinct alerts, and each of them have 4 entities in its manytomany entity field, say that across them, a couple are shared, I want to get only the distinct ones.

I'm doing this:

```
ret_list = map(lambda x: x.get_dictionary(), itertools.chain(*[alert.entities.all() for alert in
                                                                       Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(
                                                                           has_unattended=True,
                                                                           entities__related_entities__label=threat_group_label)]))

return [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in ret_list])]
```

But as I imagine, this isn't optimal at all since I end up pulling a lot of dupes and then deduping at the end. I've tried pulling the distinct value entities but that pulls me a Long that's used as a key to map the entities to the distinct alert table. Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
entity_ids = EntityToAlertMap.objects.filter(distinct_alert__has_unattended=True, 
                                             entity__related_entities__label=thread_group_label)) \
                                     .values_list('entity', flat=True).distinct()

Entity.objects.filter(id__in=entity_ids)
```

Django doc about [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: I get this: [749L, 729L, 738L, 716L, 776L, 735L] as a result instead of the entity object itself :(

Comment: I edited my answer. It's not very efficient but if you don't have a lot of entities it should do it.

Comment: Tried the edited answer, got this: 'long' object is not iterable.

Comment: What's your output of `entity_ids`? If it's a list, can you make sure that you are doing `id__in=entity_ids`? If you have `entity_ids` as one single value, it might cause the error.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, just ran it the way you wrote it, the issue with this is that each long corresponds to the mapping of one to many. So each long isn't actually an entity id. So while it returns only 6 Longs, there are actually over 20 entities associated with it.

Comment: By the way, your models are having super awkward syntax that's not compliance with python code style. You should use camel case for class names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: I didn't see the `through` keyword, so you have an intermediate model. I will edit my answer again. I'm assuming your through model has `entity` and `alert` as foreign key names.

Comment: Oh so functions are snake case but class names should be camel case?

Comment: You are misusing the `through` keyword then. It's used when you have additional attributes are needed for the m2m relationship. If you have only a m2m relationship, you don't even need `through`. Check django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: For code style in python, check pep8 doc: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Oh my apologies, yes I am using my own model for this. I mixed it up with another model that I have a similar issue with.

Comment: Added the intermediary model to my question

Comment: Ah, this technically solves part of the issue, but this only pulls those that are directly linked to the threat group itself, but it's missing the link created by the Alert. Each alert as a list of entities, but not all entities are associated with the threat group, I need to get those entities as well. Or at least that's what it seems like it's doing. Hope this cleared it up. I really appreciate your help though!